# Switching to jQuery 1.5 breaks a selector

Tags: find, jquery-1.5

just upgraded to jQuery 1.5 and now it seems the find() has problems with several selctores:

```
var $AlertColumn = $('[name=TABLE_1] tr').find('.SAPBEXstdData:eq(9), .SAPBEXstdDataOdd:eq(9), td.SAPBEXaggData:eq(9)');
```

as of 1.5 (and IE7), the thing hangs in IE7 with an error popup after a while that there's a script running forever.

It works perfect in 1.4.2.

ok here comes the code (to the first data row), I have to work on the Alert-Row which is the 9th having those classes used in find():

```
    <TABLE class=SAPBEXCellspacing cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=0 width=1250 border=0 name="TABLE_1" sizcache="5" sizset="20"><TBODY sizcache="5" sizset="20">
<TR sizcache="5" sizset="21">
<TD noWrap colSpan=19 sizcache="5" sizset="21">
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" border=0 sizcache="5" sizset="21">
<FORM name=SAPBWUForm5 action=/sap/bw/BEx?SAP-LANGUAGE=DE&amp;ITEM=TABLE_1&amp;STATE_ID=4KXJZOX5URFHG6BQFFTKAJ0OH&amp;STATELESS=X&amp;LAST_MESSAGE_ID=0 method=post sizcache="5" sizset="21">
<TBODY sizcache="5" sizset="21">
<TR sizcache="5" sizset="22">
<TD class=SAPBEXScrollVert noWrap sizcache="5" sizset="22">
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=1 border=0 sizcache="5" sizset="22">
<TBODY sizcache="5" sizset="22">
<TR>
<TD class=SAPBEXTxtStd noWrap><IMG title="Erste Zeile" alt="Erste Zeile" src="/sap/bw/Mime/BEx/Icons/page_first_row_inact.gif" border=0></TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXTxtStd noWrap><IMG title="Vorherige Zeilen" alt="Vorherige Zeilen" src="/sap/bw/Mime/BEx/Icons/page_up_inact.gif" border=0></TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXTxtStd noWrap>&nbsp;<LABEL>Zeile</LABEL></TD>
<TD noWrap><INPUT class=SAPBEXTxtFldright id=DATA_ROW_FROM title="Zeile - Maximale Anzahl: 170" onchange=document.SAPBWUForm5.submit() size=3 value=1 name=DATA_ROW_FROM></TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXTxtStd noWrap>/&nbsp;170&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXTxtStd noWrap><A title="Nächste Zeilen" href="JavaScript:SAPBW(5,'','','68')"><IMG title="Nächste Zeilen" alt="Nächste Zeilen" src="/sap/bw/Mime/BEx/Icons/page_down.gif" border=0></A></TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXTxtStd noWrap><A title="Letzte Zeile" href="JavaScript:SAPBW(5,'','','170')"><IMG title="Letzte Zeile" alt="Letzte Zeile" src="/sap/bw/Mime/BEx/Icons/page_last_row.gif" border=0></A></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></FORM></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR>
<TR></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=SAPBEXchaText noWrap>Profit Center</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXchaText noWrap>Projektleiter</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXchaText noWrap colSpan=2>Projekt</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXchaText noWrap>akt. Status</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXchaText noWrap>akt. Status Dat.</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXchaText noWrap>Kredit Datum</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXchaText noWrap>letzte Buchung</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>Kredit</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>Ist Q1 2010</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>Ist Q2 2010</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>Ist Q3 2010</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>Ist Q4 2010</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>Kredit %</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>FC Q3</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>FC Q4</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>Projektende</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>Alert</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>Notizen</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap rowSpan=7>PC100</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap rowSpan=3>Ammann Conrad</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>G000034</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>Techn. Zusammenarbeit China</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>k.a.</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>#</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>#</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>#</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdData title=0 noWrap>0</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdData noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdData noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdData noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdData title=0 noWrap>0</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdData noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdData noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdData noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdData noWrap>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdData noWrap>I NEED THIS ONE (9th) of every Data Row</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdData title=0 noWrap>
<DIV class=notiz style="TEXT-ALIGN: left"></DIV></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>G000164</TD>
<TD class=SAPBEXstdItem noWrap>Tag der offenen Tür</TD>...
```

........

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but is it possible to use an id, or at least a class on the table? Your selector is not very efficient.

Comment: cant influence the code, as its generated by sap ;-(

Comment: everytime I have to work with markup generated by SAP, I get sick and want to kill myself... I should have learned something usefull, like gardener or so ;-) I'll go back to 1.4.2 and wait until its fixed in 1.5... thanks for your help :-) – Gerald

Answer (score 0):

Try and put input in front of your selector (like `input[name=TABLE_1] tr`), because it may be that jQuery is looking through every element, including spans, divs, h1s, etc...

Comment: well the table what ever is the parent of tr :) and u should use a class, or id, just like @scotte mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Two different solutions:

- If it ain't broke, don't fix it: stay with jQuery 1.4.2. *or...*
- Rewrite the selector so that it selects more efficiently. Start with `$('table[name=TABLE_1] tr')`, and use a more specific selector in `.find()` - perhaps use `.children()` instead of `.find()`? Would need to see the actual markup for more specific suggestions.

---

**Edit** Your markup is horribly invalid. `form` is not a valid child of `table`, `name` is not a valid attribute of `table` (as pointed out by @Capsule), you're not using `nowrap` correctly... I recommend that you familiarize yourself with the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org) and go from there.

Comment: TR inside INPUT?!?? The HTML code behind this is either catastrophic, either not correct, I don't think there's a NAME attribute on TABLE

Comment: @Capsule: you're right, total typo on my part. Browsers are very lenient about allowing non-spec attributes on elements.

Comment: @Matt Ball, yeah but surprisingly, IE can sometimes be very strict and break JS with unclean HTML!

Comment: @user: paste it into your question. If you can't figure out how to show code in your question, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: will forward that to SAP ;-) I know, everytime I have to work with markup generated by SAP, I get sick and want to kill myself... I should have learned something usefull, like gardener or so ;-) I guess I fill go back to 1.4.2 and wait until its fixed in 1.5... thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Invalid selectors will very unlikely be fixed in future versions of jQuery BUT, with some luck, I've heard 1.5.1 is on its way and will fix many things...

Comment: @Capsule: what do you mean by "invalid selectors?" Do you mean things like `$('table[name=foo]')`? I'm pretty darn sure that jQuery doesn't concern itself at all with valid vs invalid markup.

Comment: It is, actually, because it's querying the DOM and the way the browser handles it.

Comment: @Capsule: well, this works just fine for me in Chrome 9: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/A46mB/

Comment: @Capsule: as I suspected, jQuery really doesn't care about the semantics of markup (in my test case - `name` not being a valid attribute on `table` elements) as far as selectors go. See [this zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8090976/110222-202813-fiddle.jshell.net-6028627.zip) from [Browsershots](http://browsershots.org/http://fiddle.jshell.net/mattball/XTzrL/show/), generated from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/XTzrL/).

Comment: @Matt Ball interesting, and copy/pasting the code of this example also works, which is puzzling, but it's not emulating the DOCTYPE (if there's any ;-)) used by @Gerald. I suspect (and I've experienced it) a different JS/DOM behaviour whith different doctypes.

Answer (score 0):

$('[name=TABLE_1] tr') seems invalid because TABLE or TBODY don't have any NAME attribute (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: as I said, this works perfectly perfect with 1.4.2... the code is generated by SAP and SAP makes messy code.

Comment: Then, as pointed out earlier, don't upgrade jQuery. The selector engine changed, hence your invalid selector not recognized anymore.